# Difference between wildfly 8 vs 10

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jax-rs, wildfly

I have a chalenge to develop an maven java ee wep application using JAX-RS, my client is using wilfly 8 and wants to upgrade in the future to wildfly 10, the question is, how can i have guidelines im my project to attempt the two versions?

Answer (score 2):

If you're building to the JAX-RS spec it won't matter. Both WildFly 8 and WildFly 10 are full Java EE 7 compliant containers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Maven profiles, one using the Maven dependencies for WildFly 8 and the other for WildFly 10.